# Помогите вытащить массив данных из цикла while. Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

Выбираю свойства элементов инфоблока:

```html
$arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "NAME", "DATE_ACTIVE_FROM", "PROPERTY_*");
    $arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID" => "14", "ACTIVE" => "Y");
    $res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array("nPageSize" => 300),  $arSelect);
    $result = Array();
    while ($ob = $res->GetNextElement()) {
        $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
        $arProps = $ob->GetProperties();
        $result = $arProps["PASSES"]["VALUE"];
        print_r($result);
    }
```

в цикле `print_r($result);` выдает массив из id свойства каждого элемента инфоблока. Но если использовать `$result`вне цикла, то выдает только один элемент. Подскажите что с этим можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

```
$arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "NAME", "DATE_ACTIVE_FROM", "PROPERTY_*");
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID" => "14", "ACTIVE" => "Y");
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array("nPageSize" => 300),  $arSelect);
$result = Array();
while ($ob = $res->GetNextElement()) {
    $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
    $arProps = $ob->GetProperties();
    $result[ $arProps["NAME"] ] = $arProps["VALUE"];
}
print_r($result);
```

попробуйте этот код.

Comment: Ошибся, тут `$result[ $arProps["NAME"] ] = $arProps["VALUE"];` измените на этот `$result[ $ob["ID"] ][ $arProps["NAME"] ] = $arProps["VALUE"];`

Comment: данный код вернет вам массив в виде `array( "ELEMENT_ID" => array( "PROP_NAME" => array or string ( PROP_VALUE ) ) )`

Comment: этот код вызывает ошибку `[Error] 
Cannot use object of type _CIBElement as array (0)`

Comment: `$result[ $ob["ID"] ][ $arProps["NAME"] ] = $arProps["VALUE"];` замени на `$result[ $arFields["ID"] ] = $arProps;`